# nullptr as undeclared type

Tags: c++, nullptr, null-pointer

I'm trying to practice the null pointer in C++, and I got nullptr as undeclared identifier.
could you please help me and tell me what is wrong ?

here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

void print(int x)
{
    std::cout << "print(int): " << x << '\n';
}

void print(int* x)
{
    if (!x)
        std::cout << "print(int*): null\n";
    else
        std::cout << "print(int*): " << *x << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    int* x = nullptr;
    print(x); // calls print(int*)

    print(nullptr);

    return 0;
}
```

thank you for your help :)

Comment: How old is your compiler?

Comment: Which compiler are you using? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr You need at least be able to compile c++11.

Comment: Need to add a compilation flag to support latest C++ standards

Comment: The program works at: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp_online.php. You must use C++0x for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

Try to compile with flag like:

```
>> g++ -std=c++11 fileName.cpp -o whatNameYouWant
```